Problem when deleting record from one2many field
I have an 'election' model with 3 different one2many fields to other relatet model 'member'. The difference between those One2Many fields is that  each of them has a different domain. The problem is that, when I tried to delete one member from one of the one2many fields using the election form (using the tree list) the aparently deleted record shows again when I click the 'save' button from the election form. Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that there are 2 different one2many relations and when you delete an element  (member) from one, The reference is intact in the other One2many fields. I am working with Odoo 17
member_ids = fields.One2many('elections.member', 'election_id', string='Members',                                
domain=[('is_observer','=', False )])        
 
observer_ids=fields.One2many('elections.member', 'election_id',string='Observers',                             
domain=[('is_observer','=', True ), ('is_candidate','=', False )])  

all_member_ids=fields.One2many('elections.member', 'election_id',string='All members (including observers and candidates)')

Inside the form
<notebook>
 <page name="members" string="Members">
  <field name="member_ids" readonly='state != "draft"'  domain="[('is_observer','=', False ), ('is_candidate','=', False )]" context="{'default_is_observer': 0, 'default_is_candidate': 0, 'from_o2m': 1}">
   <tree>
    <field name="name" />
    <field name="specialty_certificate" />
    <field name="membership_status" />
    <field name="is_candidate" />
    <button name="action_send_email_with_qr_code" type="object" string="Email with QR" invisible="membership_status!='college'" icon="fa-envelope"/>
    <button name="viixoo_cmim_elections.small_qr_report" type="action" string="Print QR" 
      invisible="membership_status != 'college'" icon="fa-print"/>
   </tree>
  </field>
 </page>
 <page name="observers" string="Observers">
  <field name="observer_ids" readonly='state != "draft"'  string="Observer" domain="[('is_observer','=', True ), ('is_candidate','=', False )]" context="{'default_is_observer': 1, 'default_is_candidate': 0, 'from_o2m': 1}">
   <tree>
    <field name="name" />
    <field name="specialty_certificate" />
    <field name="membership_status" />
    <field name="is_president" />
    <button name="action_send_email_with_qr_code" type="object" string="Email with QR"
     invisible="membership_status!='college'" icon="fa-envelope"/>
    <button name="viixoo_cmim_elections.small_qr_report" type="action" string="Print QR" 
      invisible="membership_status!='college'" icon="fa-print"/>
   </tree>
  </field>
 </page>
</notebook>


Giving feedback to answers is minimum respect, isn't it ?

It seems to me that your model-design should be modified:
instead of one model "elections.member" for both members and observers, you'd rather create 2 models:

elections.voter
elections.observer

...But If you have good reasons to keep your models-design:
Because One One2many-field always involves One many2One-field in the associated comodel, you have no other choice than creating 3 many2Many fields (that enable to create 3 different relation-tables in the database to store the 3 types of relationships independently):

class Election(models.Model):
    _name = "election"
 
    member_ids = fields.Many2many(
        comodel_name='elections.member',
        relation='election_mbrnotobs_rel',
        column1='el_id',
        column2='elmbr_id',
        string='Members', domain=[('is_observer', '=', False)])
    
    observer_ids = fields.Many2many(
        comodel_name='elections.member',
        relation='election_mbrobs_rel',
        column1='el_id',
        column2='elmbr_id',
        string='Observers', domain=[('is_observer', '=', True), ('is_candidate', '=', False)])
    
    all_member_ids = fields.Many2many(
        comodel_name='elections.member',
        relation='election_mbrall_rel',
        column1='el_id',
        column2='elmbr_id',
        string='All members (including observers and candidates)')



The issue is caused by using the same many2one field (election_id) for
all three One2many fields. When you delete a record from one One2many
field, Odoo does not truly remove the record from the database—it only
changes the reference field (election_id). Since all three One2many
fields are filtered by domain but share the same election_id field,
the record still exists and reappears when the form is saved.

class ElectionMember(models.Model):
    _name = 'elections.member'
    _description = 'Election Member'

    election_id_member = fields.Many2one('elections.election', string='Election (Members)')
    election_id_observer = fields.Many2one('elections.election', string='Election (Observers)')
    election_id_all = fields.Many2one('elections.election', string='Election (All Members)')
    # Other fields...


class Election(models.Model):
    _name = 'elections.election'
    _description = 'Election'

    member_ids = fields.One2many(
        'elections.member', 'election_id_member', string='Members',
        domain=[('is_observer', '=', False)]
    )

    observer_ids = fields.One2many(
        'elections.member', 'election_id_observer', string='Observers',
        domain=[('is_observer', '=', True), ('is_candidate', '=', False)]
    )

    all_member_ids = fields.One2many(
        'elections.member', 'election_id_all', string='All Members (including Observers and Candidates)'
    )


This solution will create three separate relational tables in the
database for each One2many relation. This is because each many2one
field will maintain its own relationship.
If you anticipate a large dataset, this approach might impact
performance due to the extra joins between these tables.


If your use case can be satisfied with a Many2many relationship, it is a best practice to use it instead of multiple One2many fields. This reduces database complexity by avoiding the creation of separate relational tables and improves performance.
class Election(models.Model):
    _name = 'elections.election'
    _description = 'Election'

    member_ids = fields.Many2many(
        'elections.member', 'election_member_rel', 
        'election_id', 'member_id', string='Members',
        domain=[('is_observer', '=', False)]
    )

    observer_ids = fields.Many2many(
        'elections.member', 'election_observer_rel', 
        'election_id', 'observer_id', string='Observers',
        domain=[('is_observer', '=', True), ('is_candidate', '=', False)]
    )

    all_member_ids = fields.Many2many(
        'elections.member', 'election_all_member_rel', 
        'election_id', 'all_member_id', string='All Members (including Observers and Candidates)'
    )

